# Navigation: Show current function name / if/switch depth etc

Tags: navigation

I'm struggling to explain what I want, and I do not even know if something like this is possible in vim.

I code in PHP / JavaScript.

In a large file, I would like a statusbar to show me:

- which function the cursor is currently in (this is the main one I want).
- if possible: what control structures I'm currently in (if/switch/etc).

e.g:

```
file.php > my_function() > if > if > switch > while
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to consider installing the [context](https://github.com/wellle/context.vim) plugin.

It make sure the context lines (function, switch, if) keep visible as long as they are relevant to analyze the code you browse (the current line of the cursor).

Comment: Wow! From the animated demo, it looks great.  Thanks!

Comment: I have a shortcut to toggle it on or off. I find it very useful to analyze long functions or long ifs ;-)